# Does std::ranges::to allow converting to a std::map?

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

In the `std::ranges::to` paper wg21.link/p1206 ths overview section has the following

```
//Supports converting associative container to sequence containers
auto f = ranges::to<vector>(m);
```

However I can't find where the detail of converting to a `std::map` is descibed in the rest of the paper. I tried range-v3 and Sy Brand's implementation of `ranges::to` in https://github.com/TartanLlama/ranges and neither of them compiles code converting a range to a `std::map`. So is this just missing from those libraries or is converting to a `std::map` not really intended to be allowed?

Comment: Right there, in the paper you linked, on page 3 you have the following: `auto g = ranges::to<map>(f);`. So apparently it is intended to be allowed. Whether it is implemented anywhere beyond Niebler's range-v3—I don't know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does `std::ranges::to` allow converting to a `std::map`?

Yes.

> I tried range-v3 and Sy Brand's implementation of `ranges::to` in https://github.com/TartanLlama/ranges and neither of them compiles code converting a range to a `std::map`

I haven't tried Sy's implementation, and it looks like range-v3's implementation is weirdly broken:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

    // this works (explicit)
    // m1 is a std::map<int, int>
    auto m1 = ranges::to<std::map<int, int>>(v);

    // this works (deduced with a pipe)
    // m2 is a std::map<int, int>
    auto m2 = v | ranges::to<std::map>();

    // but this does not (deduced, direct call)
    auto m3 = ranges::to<std::map>(v);
}
```

The issue is that the class template direct call version in range-v3 for some reason specifically tries to instantiate `C<range_value_t<R>>` (which would be `std::map<std::pair<int, int>>` in this case, clearly wrong) even though there is a metafunction here already that does the right thing and would deduce `std::map<int, int>` (used by the pipe version).

The `ranges::to` in the standard library specifies these two to do the same (correct) thing, so this will work in C++23. This is just an easy bug fix in range-v3.

Comment: "*I haven't tried Sy's implementation.*" It [works as expected](https://godbolt.org/z/5co569vK6).

Comment: Thanks for that, I should have stated in my post I was trying Visual Studio not GCC. The fact that GCC works is good to know

Answer (score 6):

> So is this just missing from those libraries or is converting to a
> `std::map` not really intended to be allowed?

### std::map to std::vector:

According to the description of [[range.utility.conv.to]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/ranges#range.utility.conv.to), this

```
map<int, double> m;
auto f = ranges::to<vector>(m);
```

will invoke the following overload

> ```
> template<template<class...> class C, input_­range R, class... Args>
>   constexpr auto to(R&& r, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> Let *`DEDUCE_­EXPR`* be defined as follows:
>
> - `C(declval<R>(), declval<Args>()...)` if that is a valid expression,
> - otherwise, `C(from_­range, declval<R>(), declval<Args>()...)` if that is a valid expression,
> - otherwise, `C(declval<input-iterator>(), declval<input-iterator>(), declval<Args>()...)` if that is a valid expression,
> - otherwise, the program is ill-formed.
>
> *Returns*: `to<decltype(DEDUCE_­EXPR)>(std​::​forward<R>(r), std​::​forward<Args>(args)...)`.

Where `C` is `vector`, `R` is `map<int, double>&`, and `Args...` is empty parameter pack. Note that C++23 introduces the following [range version constructor](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/vector#cons-11) for `vector`

> ```
> template<container-compatible-range<T> R>
>   constexpr vector(from_range_t, R&& rg, const Allocator& = Allocator());
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Constructs a vector object with the elements of the range `rg`,
> using the specified allocator.

and the following CTAD

```
template<ranges::input_­range R, class Allocator = allocator<ranges::range_value_t<R>>>
  vector(from_range_t, R&&, Allocator = Allocator())
    -> vector<ranges::range_value_t<R>, Allocator>;
```

So `C(from_range, declval<R>())` is a valid expression, and the type of *`DEDUCE_EXPR`* will be `vector<pair<const int, double>>`, which will further invoke

```
to<vector<pair<const int, double>>>(m);
```

which will construct a `vector` with `value_type` of `pair<const int, double>` through the range version constructor.

So `ranges::to<vector>(m)` in C++23  is basically equivalent to

```
map<int, double> m;
vector f(m.begin(), m.end());
```

---

The reason [range-v3 fails](https://godbolt.org/z/7cn441Wvf) is that its internal implementation detects that `vector<pair<const int, double>>` is reservable, so it will first default construct the `vector` and call `v.reserve()` to pre-allocate the memory, and then copy the `map` by calling `v.assign()`, but since `pair<const int, double>` is not copy assignable, so compilation fails.

<sub>I suspect this is an implementation bug of range-v3, since it would compile if the `vector`'s `reserve()` function didn't exist, and this optimized overload doesn't seem to constrain that the `value_type` must be copy-assignable.</sub>

### std::vector to std::map:

And for the following

```
auto g = ranges::to<map>(f);
```

Since `std::map` also has the [following constructors](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/associative#map.cons-5) and corresponding CATD in in C++23

```
template<container-compatible-range<value_type> R>
  map(from_range_t, R&& rg, const Compare& comp = Compare(), const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

So following the same rules of the game, we will get a `map<int, double>`.